# how do you add avatar image as background image in this animated div?

Tags: css, animation, rotation, background-image, linear-gradients

I want to add my avatar inside this circular div which has some rotation animation. I want to be able to fit my avatar inside this circle container. I did it as a backgound-image but i am having this problem:

[image: avatar-container]

```
<div className = 'avatar-container'>
</div>


.avatar-container{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.avatar-container::before{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(from 90deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) 70%, rgb(11 78 230/ 9%) 80%, rgb(0 220 255) 100%);
    content: '';
    left: -25%;
    top: -25%;
    animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;

}

.avatar-container::after{
    position: absolute;
    width: 94%;
    height: 94%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('./avatar.jpeg');
    content: '';
    top: 3%;
    left: 3%;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? We don’t have access to your avatar so can’t see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `background-size: cover;` to `avatar-container::after`

```css
.avatar-container{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;

}


.avatar-container::before{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(from 90deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) 70%, rgb(11 78 230/ 9%) 80%, rgb(0 220 255) 100%);
    content: '';
    left: -25%;
    top: -25%;
    animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;

}

.avatar-container::after{
    position: absolute;
    width: 94%;
    height: 94%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nnhI.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    content: '';
    top: 3%;
    left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />


</head>

<body>

  <div class = 'avatar-container'>
  </div>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful and it worked